# How to make a prepared statement without explicit quotes in case of string variables

Tags: python, mysql

I use `MySQLdb` library. When I make a query like this

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM srcdst WHERE TABLESRC = ?", src)
```

where src is a string variable, I get an error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I also get an error, if I make it like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM srcdst WHERE TABLESRC = %s" % src)
```

However, I do not have an error in this case:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM srcdst WHERE TABLESRC = '%s'" % src)
```

But what I do not like about this statement is explicit quotes around `%s`. I would like to make the driver decide the type of variable and do it implicitly. Otherwise, in case of automatic queries it would be a real problem to do all this routine of parsing variable types and "preparing" a prepared statement.

**EDIT**

It seems, as if I found a solution. The right syntax was:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM srcdst WHERE TABLESRC = %s" , (src,))
```

where the variables (`src`) is provided as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

**'src'** in your code means values that you want to pass instead of question mark. If that is true try the below code. Else ignore

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM srcdst WHERE TABLESRC = " + src);
```

Comment: Thanks! But what would you do in case of a more difficult `WHERE` block? Concatenate a long long list? That does not seem to be a pretty solution

Comment: I think, where ever you want to pass the values in your where statement follow the same process that I have mentioned above

Comment: And by the way, your solution does not work. If TABLESRC was of integer type, then it probably would. But as I said, I have a string variable. That is the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

Then try this

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM srcdst WHERE TABLESRC like '%" + src + "%'");
```

Comment: Sorry, but that has nothing to do with my question. My question is not about how to find something in a table. My question was about making a prepared statement.

Comment: And even in your example you use explicit single quotes, whereas I said, that I need driver to decide implicitly the type of a variable

Answer (score 0):

It seems, as if I found a solution. The right syntax was:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM srcdst WHERE TABLESRC = %s" , (src,))
```

where the variables (`src`) is provided as a tuple.